# Bootstrap panel at bottom panel

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float

I did a fiddle to explain my example: http://jsfiddle.net/ag76W/

I want one div at bottom other div with bootstrap, but this only happens when the screen is mobile or tablet. In a normal screen my second div set at right of first.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 animated bounceInLeft">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>
                <span class="panel-title text">titulo</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 animated bounceInDown">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>
                <span class="panel-title text" ng-bind="company.company"/>
                <span class="pull-right" style="margin-left:1em;">
                <span>aaaa</span>                
                <span class="pull-right" style="margin-left:1em;"></span>
            </div>             
        </div>   
    </div>
</div>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it..onlye set float none at first div.

Copy the code for if help anyone.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 animated bounceInLeft" style="float:none !importnant">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>
                <span class="panel-title text">titulo</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 animated bounceInDown">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>
                <span class="panel-title text" ng-bind="company.company"/>
                <span class="pull-right" style="margin-left:1em;">
                <span> aaaa</span>                
                <span class="pull-right" style="margin-left:1em;"></span>
          </div>             
    </div>   
</div>
</div>
```